# Using data from hidden table column

Tags: javascript, sql, visual-studio

Is there a way to access cell data in a table column if the entire column is hidden. I produced my table using visual studio and the data is sourced from oracle. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Also, how is the column hidden? CSS? Javascript? Backend code?

Comment: Show the `td` with javascript, get your data and hide it again...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you set a column to be invisible in .NET , it won't be displayed in your HTML code so obviously there's no way to get anything from it in javascript (as you tagged you question javascript I presume that's what you're trying to achieve).

Either you treat this data server-side, in .NET, either you let the column appear in your HTML and just hide it with css...

Comment: Correct. My server-side knowledge is very limited, so using css would be the easier solution for me.

Comment: So instead of hiding your column in net, adda class to it, that way you can easily hide it in CSS. Just be aware that your data is totally visible to anyone though, it will be in the source of the page...

Comment: That's totally fine its only a concept application at this point. I'm using javascript to grab the data in the last column to execute functional logic, but I need the column hidden at the same time. {display:none} is the property I should use..